# How to serve MPA frontend with SSR backend using Next.js?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, next.js, material-ui

I have recently bought an MUI template. I am using React with Next.js and Flask as my backend. The MUI template is Multiple-Page Application. I have used Flask for a SPA before which I just had to `return send_from_directory('./static/', 'index.html')` one time so that I would server the static files from the frontend. I am guessing I am not supposed to return the html page for every route there is in Flask like below:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/signUp')
def login():
    return render_template('signUp.html')

@app.route('/home')
def login():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

How can I combine a MPA template with my SSR backend Flask? How can I configure Next.js to do this? This is what the template contains:

[image]

I tried writing my Flask code like this but it does not seem to work well:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def serve_nextjs():
    return send_from_directory("./static", "index.html")

# Serve the static Next.js files (CSS, JavaScript, images, etc.)
@app.route("/<path:filename>")
def serve_static(filename):
    print(filename)
    if '/' in filename:
        print("1")
        return send_from_directory("./static", filename)
    else:
        print("goto2")
        return send_from_directory(f"./static/{filename}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this can be simplified through:

```
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def serve_page(path):
    return send_from_directory(f'./static/{path}', "index.html")
```

Additionally, if you have static files in different locations, they can be specified like so:

```
@app.route('/_next/<path:filename>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def next_static_files(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder + '/_next/', filename)

@app.route('/assets/<path:filename>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def assets_files(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder + '/assets/', filename)
```